# Making a collection view scroll out side menu swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I've looked all over the place for an answer and can't find one. I'm creating an app that has a menu that pops out from the left side using a button and animations. The menu itself is a collection view. Currently when the menu button is pressed, the entire collection view pops out from the left side. I want to do this same thing, but I want the collection view to respond to a swipe from left to right. Please keep in mind I don't want the individual things INSIDE the collection view to move, but the collection view itself as a whole menu. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Update the menus position using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

Comment: Did my answer address you issue?

Comment: @JRK777 Glad to hear it worked! Would you mind marking my answer with the checkmark? :)

Answer (score 0):

Good evening!

If i understand your question correctly. You simply have a button which you want to use to animate a slide in of a UICollectionView. Here is what I would do:

1. Create a new collection view class: (if you want a different frame size of the collectionView remember to change it in both animations as well as the initial setup in `showSlideCollectionView`

   ```
   import UIKit

   class CollectionViewLauncher : NSObject {

   lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
       cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
       return cv
   }()

   // reuseidentifier for the cells in the collectionview
   let cellId = "cellId"

   var viewController: UIViewController?

   func showSlideCollectionView() {

       if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

           window.addSubview(collectionView)

           let width: CGFloat = window.frame.width * 0.55

           //this is the original frame for the collectionview (so it is off screen by default)
           collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: -window.frame.width, y: 0, width: width, height: window.frame.height)

           //this animates the collectionview on screen
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

               self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: window.frame.height)

           }, completion: nil)

       }
   }

   func hideSlideCollectionView() {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
           //sliding the collectionview off screen
           if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
               self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: window.frame.width, y: 0, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
           }
       }, completion: nil)
   }

   override init() {
       super.init()
       collectionView.dataSource = self
       collectionView.delegate = self

       //register your own cell class type here. The code wont work unless you create a cell class of type UICollectionViewCell and customise it there and then register the cell here. (you can also create a nib file and register that.
       collectionView.register(YourCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


       }
   }

   extension CollectionViewLauncher: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return 3
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! YourCell //your cell class

           //setup what you need in the cells
           return cell
     }

         //add additional UICollectionView Data source methods if you need further customisation of the collectionview.
   }
   ```
2. Register your cell class in the `overrode init()` method inside the `CollectionViewLauncher`.
3. In the your ViewController do the following.

   ```
      lazy var collectionViewLauncher : CollectionViewLauncher = {
           let launcher = CollectionViewLauncher()
           launcher.viewController = self
           return launcher
      }()

          //in your button action you call the following to animate the collection view to appear. 
          collectionViewLauncher.showSlideCollectionView()

          //when you want it to dissapear call the following to animate it away (perhaps in a UITapGestureRecognizer or something).
          collectionViewLauncher.hideSlideCollectionView()

      //example button action
      @objc func yourButtonsAction(sender: UIButton) {
          collectionViewLauncher.showSlideCollectionView()
      }
   ```

**Edit:**

If you have data that you need to pass to this collection view from your view controller i would recommend implementing it directly in the same class as your view controller instead. (Just do exactly the same but put the stuff in the `init()` method in viewDidLoad instead and the rest within the ViewController class).

- If you want it to be slidable using a drag gesture instead. You should use the approach in the edit here and then use a pan gesture to move it instead of the show/hideSlideCollectionView methods.

I hope this helps.